# Dual boot elementary OS on SSD and Windows 10 on separate HDD?

Tags: dual-boot, disk-management

I currently have elementary OS Freya installed on a 250GB SSD. I have a 1TB HDD that hasn't been plugged into my computer yet. I was wondering, is it possible to plug this 2nd HDD into my computer, install Windows on it, then choose which drive to boot into at startup?  If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply install windows on your extra HDD. And keep booting from your SDD. Than just do `sudo update-grub`. To make grub detect your new windows installation. Next time your startup, you can select windows in your boot menu.